# Wrap the history number - reset history number without losing history

Tags: command-line, bash, history, command-history

I display the history number as part of my prompt, e.g.,

```
{!1123}(j:~)$ ls /some/long/and/hard/to/type/path
```

so that I can do it later with `!1123`. My `HISTSIZE` and `HISTFILESIZE` are both 200, but this doesn't prevent the history number (`\!` in the prompt) from hitting quadruple digits because I use tmux. I want my prompt and history commands to be shorter. Is there a way to have the history wrap, such that when I hit some number the history number of the next command is set to 1, and only overwrite old commands as I reuse their history numbers? Example:

```
{!1}(j:~)$ ls /first/path
...
{!498}(j:~)$ ls /some/path
{!499}(j:~)$ ls /some/other/path
#at some target number, history number resets
{!1}(j:~)$ ls /new/path
#but remembers the old commands til they're overwritten
{!2}(j:~)$ !498
ls /some/path
#and keeps incrementing and overwriting the oldest commands
{!3}(j:~)$ !1
ls /new/path
```

Comment: *»quadruple digits because I use tmux«* I doubt tmux is the problem. When I use plain bash with `HISTSIZE=3` I also get bigger history entries. Maybe you find something useful in `help history`.

Comment: @Socowi, you are right that tmux isn't the problem, it's how long you stay logged in during a session, since the number will increment regardless of HISTSIZE and HISTFILESIZE. I just meant that with tmux my sessions are generally very long. `help history` is a paragraph long and I have already read it. I can clear history, but I can't reset the history number and keep old entries.

Comment: With `exec bash` the history numbers are reset, but also local variables are lost. Alternatively, would you be interested in a "solution" where history number 31415 is displayed as 415? That really means displayed. You still had to type `!31415` to execute that history entry.

Comment: @Socowi, I want to only type the shorter version as well. Is it possible to alias the history somehow, so that if `!1123` was valid, `!123` would expand to that. It wouldn't have to be super extensible, i.e., only deal with 4 digit history numbers, not 5+.

Comment: I've never heard that it's possible to modify how bash expands things like `!123`. You probably would had to fork bash, but then you could directly implement history number wrapping yourself.

Comment: @Socowi, jesus. That's too far. Ah well. Thanks for your help.